# Fetching large numbers of rows with relationship to each row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I found the `chunk` method in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#chunking-results) that helps to retrieve thousands of records. Although, it's still unclear how efficiently get related models. Right now my best try:

```
Student::chunk(100, function ($students){
      foreach ($students as $student){
          $student->with(['campus','program','group'])->get();
      };
});
```

That leads me to the result of `1996ms; 2009 queries, 1996 of which are duplicated`.
This is in a test environment where I have 3500 rows in the `students` table.

In product env it will be more 23k rows. How to improve querying the data in the case with the relationship if model `student` has `belongsTo` relationship to `campuses`,`programs` and `groups` tables?

**Student.php**

```
public function campus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Campus::class);
}

public function program()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

And the second question would be, how to send that data to the blade?
I guess just put it in a variable not the solution because the variable can be run out of memory....or I wrong?

**UPDATE:**
@Pavel Lint 's hint significantly decrease amount of queries, but still, half of them are duplicated:

[image]

Comment: Have you done the database indexing properly? Also, I always find that raw queries perform better than eloquent. Use `joins` where necessary. If you have not, maybe you should give it a go too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this you'll be better off if doing the opposite:

```php
Student::with(['campus','program','group'])->chunk(100, function ($students){
    // your logic here
});
```

To send all the data to blade, you can accumulate it in a single array and send it to the view.

Comment: Thanks! 24 queries, 10 of which are duplicated.

Much better now, but still have duplicated queries. Any idea why do they appear?

Comment: Duplicated how? Could they just have different OFFSET because you're using `chunk`?

Comment: I use `Telescope` to check duplication

Comment: well could you share the duplicated queries?

Comment: The screenshot has been attached to the main post. Please take a look

Comment: what exactly are you doing inside the chunk callback function now?

Comment: I do nothing, right now. But Ill `array_push` them to an array in order to send to a view

Comment: I don't see a problem with your queries at the moment. You can see that you get 3 queries (one per each relation) and a main query of 100 students. That repeats for each chunk as expected.

Comment: What do you do in your view then? if you access things that are not included in the with statement it can make a query. And chunk will automatically produce some queries, each every round. But why are you chunking and pushing to array, why not just get all at once then?

Answer (score 0):

When sending to blade, don't forget (or you might like to know that) Laravel has built-in pagination options.

So you don't have to use chunk as the pagination will limit the query size - and it has the added benefit of providing a pagination UI functionality (which I am guessing is what you're after when you say "sending to blade".

[Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination)

So maybe something like this:

```
$studsPerPage = 20; // or however many students you want to display at a time
$students = Student::with(['campus','program','group'])->paginate($studsPerPage);
```

And then in your blade UI:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($students as $stud)
        {{ $stud->name }} And student details
    @endforeach
</div>

use this cool pagination tool to surf over pages of Studs
{{ $students->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Yajra Datatable Package for managing data it will help you yajra is a third party tool . it provides you pagination but pagination is already included in laravel but there is another benefit yajra pravides you ajax live search as well.

for installation run command :

**composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle**

After that you need to set providers and alias.

config/app.php

**'providers' => [
    ....
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
]**

**'aliases' => [
    ....
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]**

In this is step we need to create route for datatables layout file and another one for getting data. so open your routes/web.php file and add following route.

routes/web.php

**Route::get('Students', ['uses'=>'StudentController@index', 'as'=>'Students.index']);**

then is Student Controller

```
  public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Student::latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){

                       $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('Students');
}
```

In Last step, let's create Students.blade.php(resources/views/Students.blade.php) for layout and we will write design code here and put following code:

resources/views/Students.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel </title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th width="100px">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('Students.index') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });

  });
</script>
</html>
```

then:

**php artisan serve**

now open browser goto your route

**http://localhost:8000/Students**